# Reference objects in kivy added with python

Tags: python, kivy

I need to know how to reference dynamically created objects. Like in the example, how can I change text of the buttons after creation? Normaly I would do it using their ids, but as far as I know, you can't give ids to objects created in python.

.py code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import mainthread

NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS = 5


class MapScreen(Screen):

    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self):
        for i in range(NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS):
            button = Button(text="B_" + str(i))
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)

class Test(App):
    pass


Test().run()
```

.kv code

```
ScreenManager:
  MapScreen:

<MapScreen>:
  name: 'map'

  GridLayout:
    id: grid
    cols: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep a list of the `Buttons`:

```
def on_enter(self):
    self.buttons = []
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS):
        button = Button(text="B_" + str(i))
        self.buttons.append(button)
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)
```

or you could create your own dictionary:

```
def on_enter(self):
    self.buttons = {}
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS):
        text = "B_" + str(i)
        button = Button(text=text)
        self.buttons[text] = button
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)
```